# Applying style EditText elements

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm developing a an Android Application.

To make the UI more attractive i want to shrunk the EditText text and apply background color and shape.

I must also be able to remove that element from EditText.

Have a look at this 
[Google plus App](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=isch&tbnid=NXeLGq_hZcZ1SM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.androidsocialmedia.com/apps/google-plus-rolled-out-in-a-big-way-with-android-app&docid=YjG1NjInIbTFlM&imgurl=http://www.androidsocialmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/google-plus-android-5.jpg&w=480&h=800&ei=N6WBT7uKBYPQrQfckM3PBQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=562&vpy=233&dur=1253&hovh=290&hovw=174&tx=94&ty=103&sig=105716919121830335083&page=1&tbnh=149&tbnw=89&start=0&ndsp=21&ved=1t:429,r:16,s:0,i:101)

Answer (score 1):

Use this as an Xml file to round your EditText and set the color to whatever you want...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"  android:topRightRadius="8dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dip"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont  want to apply styles for edittext,the edit text contents contains comma separated text.i want to apply styles to them

Comment: Read your question again where does it specify that you wanted styling for the text within the edit text?